# Как сохранять данные из формы в JSON файл?

Tags: php, json

С помощью скрипта ниже сохраняю в json файл post данные, сохраняет в таком виде:

```
{"name":"Bot","email":"bot@bot.ru"}
```

Каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку Submit данные в json файле просто добавляются так:

```
{"name":"Bot","email":"bot@bot.ru"}{"name":"Bot","email":"bot@bot.ru"}{"name":"Bot","email":"bot@bot.ru"}
```

Как сделать, чтобы данные продолжали сохраняться в **валидный json файл**, по этому образцу:

```
[{"name":"Bot","email":"bot@bot.ru"},{"name":"Bot2","email":"bot2@bot2.ru"}]
```

Код формы:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$file = "data.json";
$arr = array(
    'name'     => $_POST['name'],
    'email'    => $_POST['email']
);
$json_string = json_encode($arr);
file_put_contents($file, $json_string, FILE_APPEND);
//    echo $json_string;
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center;">
<h1>Form</h1>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <p>
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your full name" autofocus required>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="email">Email: </label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
    </p>
    <p style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Спасибо!

UP.

Добился нужного формата с помощью функций file_get_contents и str_replace
но как-то криво это все (((

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$file = "data.json";
$arr = array(
    'name'     => $_POST['name'],
    'email'    => $_POST['email']
);
$json_string = json_encode($arr);
file_put_contents($file, '['.$json_string.']', FILE_APPEND);

}

// Если включены строгие типы, то есть объявлено (strict_types=1);
$file = file_get_contents('data.json', true);
$file = str_replace('][', ',', $file);
echo $file;
?>
```

Comment: Декодировать текущие данные, добавить к ним новые, перезаписать файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На ум пришли лишь 2 способа:

1. Считывать весь файл и преобразовывать в массив, после чего,
   добавлять новую запись в массив и снова перезаписывать файл этим
   содержимым.
2. Если записей много, то вырезать последний ']' в файле,
       записывать в конец `','.$json_string.']'`.

---

Попробуйте еще поискать в интернете знания на тему json файл как база данных.
Еще можно использовать sqlLite базу данных это тоже файл и php из коробки умеет с ней работать.
Если не критичен json, то можно так же заменить способ хранения на csv файл.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно, нужнопопробовать sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вроде такого. Возможно, вам нужно создавать новый файл, если до этого данных не записывалось.

```
$file = "data.json";
$data = file_get_contents($file);
if (empty($data)) {
    $json = [];
} else {
    $json = json_decode($data, $assoc = TRUE);
}
$arr = array(
    'name'     => $_POST['name'],
    'email'    => $_POST['email']
);

array_push($json, $arr);
$json_string = json_encode($json);
file_put_contents($file, $json_string);
```