# Как отправить данные в формате json с формы на локальный сервер? React, node.js

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs

Нужно отправить данные из формы в `json` файл и отрисовать эти данные. Форма выглядит вот так:

```html
<form action="тут должен быть сервер" method="post" id="createPost">
  <div>
    <div>
      <label for="name">Имя</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="username"></input>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="content">Текст поста</label>
      <textarea id="content" name="description"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input value="submit" type="submit"></input>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1122097/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B2-json-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB

Comment: нужно использовать javascript